# Opening Google Maps V2 InfoWindow automatically when map and marker loads

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

How do you call a markers' infowindow to open when the map loads.  For some reason the Google documentation only shows how to respond to a click action. I'm not very good with JavaScript so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

this is my current code, but for some reason, no map appears.  But there is no error to help me pinpoint the problem...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {

var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
var point = new GLatLng(53.3407791, -6.2596385);

map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.setCenter(point, 16);

// Set up three markers with info windows 
var html = 'South Anne Street,<br />Dublin 2, Ireland';
var marker = new GMarker(point);

map.addOverlay(marker);
marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);     // This opens the info window automatically

GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
});

}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.   Figured it out. in V3 just add infowindow.open(map, marker) see folowing code.. var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  
  content: 'Hello world',
  position: latlng,
  
}); 
infowindow.open(map, marker);